# How to display only one item at a time on the screen in gallery in android?

Tags: android, gallery

I have a gallery, Which contains some items. I want that only one item should be display at a time on the screen other should be invisible. When user do next then only next item should be displayed on the screen. How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these are available options for you

1.Use `android:spacing="custopm_value dip"`
2.Write a `CustomGallery`
3.Show an image which occupy the whole screen from the Gallery.

Comment: How to do the same with CustomGallery?

Comment: Why are you not using `android:spacing` ? I think its better than `CustomGallery`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i know which image is in the middle or means showing currently in the gallery?